# Which are the sins that will not be forgiven in the age to come?

Tags: catholicism, exegesis, sin, gospel-of-matthew, unforgivable-sin

At Matthew 12:32 we hear some tough talk from Jesus:

> Whoever speaks a word against the Son of Man will be forgiven, but whoever speaks against the Holy Spirit will not be forgiven, either in this age or in the age to come.

I wish to know whether there are other sins which fall in the category of those which   will not be forgiven in the age to come , say, desecration of the Holy Euchariat , or say,  murder of an ordained priest .  What do the Catholic Church teach about the sins which may not be forgiven in the age to come.

Answer (score 2):

Actually our sermon was on just that topic.  Father said the unforgiveable sin is the one that denies Jesus for in denying Jesus you deny the Father.
Thus you believe that God is not loving nor generous and can do all things. 
No there is no other sin greater than that.. all sins can be forgiven but once you denied God there is really is nothing left for you. People that deny God also deny there is any hope, it all leads to despair which is where Satan wants you to be so he take your soul as his own.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site, I think this answer might be improved if you can show how what you're stating here is Catholic in line with doctrine.  I'm Catholic and a moderator on the site and generally amenable to answers that come straight from priests, but it has to be very clear which parts of your answer you consider primary sources and which parts are your personal extrapolation.   So I'm going to put a "needs improvement" sticker on this post and delete eventually after a while unless you can edit in how you're sure this is in accord with Catholic doctrine.

Answer (score 1):

If souls go hell, there has to be a reason for it!

> In Christian [hamartiology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamartiology), eternal sins, unforgivable sins, or unpardonable sins are sins which will not be forgiven by God. One eternal or unforgivable sin (blasphemy against the Holy Spirit) is specified in several passages of the Synoptic Gospels, including Mark 3:28-29, Matthew 12:31-32, and Luke 12:10.
>
> In Roman Catholic teaching there are six sins that blaspheme against the Holy Spirit. They are: 1. Despair (believing that one's evil is beyond God's forgiveness); 2. Presumption (glory without merit, that is, hope of salvation without keeping the Commandments, or expectation of pardon for sin without repentance); 3. Envying the goodness of another (sadness or repining at another's growth in virtue and perfection); 4. Obstinacy in sin (willful persisting in wickedness, and running on from sin to sin, after sufficient instructions and admonition); 5. Final impenitence (to die without either confession or contrition for our sins), and 6. Impugning the known truth (to argue against known points of faith, and this includes misrepresenting parts or all of the Christian faith to make it seem undesirable). [(1)](https://www.catholic.com/qa/what-is-the-sin-of-presumption), [(2)](https://forums.catholic.com/t/the-six-sins-against-the-holy-spirit/217844/2), [(3)](https://www.catholic.com/quickquestions/what-are-sins-that-cry-to-heaven-for-vengeance-and-sins-against-the-holy-spirit) - [Eternal sin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_sin)

Answer (score 1):

St. Augustine understood this passage in terms of purgatory. That is, while some sins will be forgiven in purgatory, the sin Jesus talks about here cannot be.

> For some of the dead, indeed, the prayer of the Church or of pious individuals is heard; but it is for those who, having been regenerated in Christ, did not spend their life so wickedly that they can be judged unworthy of such compassion, nor so well that they can be considered to have no need of it. As also, after the resurrection, there will be some of the dead to whom, after they have endured the pains proper to the spirits of the dead, mercy shall be accorded, and acquittal from the punishment of the eternal fire. For were there not some whose sins, though not remitted in this life, shall be remitted in that which is to come, it could not be truly said, “They shall not be forgiven, neither in this world, neither in that which is to come.” (City of God, Book 21, chapter 24).

Answer (score 0):

For the Catholic Church, the sins that are not forgiven are mortal sins unrepented.  All other sins may be forgiven.

> 1864 "Therefore I tell you, every sin and blasphemy will be forgiven men, but the blasphemy against the Spirit will not be forgiven."136 There are no limits to the mercy of God, but anyone who deliberately refuses to accept his mercy by repenting, rejects the forgiveness of his sins and the salvation offered by the Holy Spirit.137 Such hardness of heart can lead to final impenitence and eternal loss.

[Final impenitence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_sin) is eternal damnation.  But it requires the following.

> 1874 To choose deliberately - that is, both knowing it and willing it - something gravely contrary to the divine law and to the ultimate end of man is to commit a mortal sin. This destroys in us the charity without which eternal beatitude is impossible. Unrepented, it brings eternal death.

What is grave or mortal sin?

> 1857 For a sin to be mortal, three conditions must together be met: "Mortal sin is sin whose object is grave matter and which is also committed with full knowledge and deliberate consent."131
>
> 1858 Grave matter is specified by the Ten Commandments...

So, with full knowledge and deliberate consent, if one breaks any of the Ten Commandments, and does not repent, and dies in that state, those mortal sins are unforgiven.

Answer (score -2):

Which are the sins that will not be forgiven in the age to come?

"Whoever speaks a word against the Son of Man will be forgiven, but whoever speaks against the Holy Spirit will not be forgiven, either in this age or in the age to come."(Matthew12:32)

From the above reference verse, it clearly distinguished the difference between sins against the Son of Man/Jesus versus the sin against the Holy Spirit.

The BIG QUESTION here is, how can you speak a word against the Holy Spirit, we all know Jesus became God-Man but the Holy Spirit did not incarnate.
Jesus addressed this to the crowd and Pharisees, saying anyone who publicly attributes the work of the Holy Spirit to the devil/satan is the "UNFORGIVABLE SIN"

As Christian we know the scriptures teaches us that our body is the temple of the Holy Spirit, and the Holy Spirit can dwell in a believer to inspire his thought,words and action.

If you are asking for Catholic perspective let me stated the reflection of St.Maximillian Kolbe about the Lourdes Apparition Mary saying "I AM" the Immaculate Conception" instead of saying I am immaculately conceived...
St.Kolbe...stated the Immaculate Conception is divine, St.Kolbe is pointing to the Holy Spirit as the Uncreated Immaculate Conception and Mary as the created Immaculate Conception (p.52 book of Fr.Gaitley 33Days to Morning Glory)

The Mystery of Truth lies in the mystical union between the Holy Spirit & Mary(as Spouse/Advocate).

What type of union is this? It is above all an interior union, a union of her essence with the "essence" of the Holy Spirit.The Holy Spirit dwells in her,lives in her. This was true from the first instant of her existence.It was always true, it will always be true.(p.53 book of Fr.Gaitley 33Days to Morning Glory)

What does St.Kolbe driving at his reflections.If Satan can possessed the body of a human submitting to his powers. Mary by Her FIAT and Total Surrender to God's WILL, enable the Holy Spirit to animates her thought, words & actions.In the words of St.Kolbe Mary is "POSSESSED/ANIMATED" completely and perfectly by the Holy Spirit.

Now from the approved Catholic Church Marian Apparition at Fatima in 1917. Sis. Lucia gave the five blasphemy against Blessed Virgin Mary.

The verse now in reference(Matthew12:32) and the words of Jesus pointing to anyone who publicly attributed the works of the Holy Spirit to the devil is the UNFORGIVABLE SIN.

The reflections of St.Kolbe on the Mystical Union of the Holy Spirit & Mary points to all approved Marian Apparitions clearly is the work of the Holy Spirit.

Please see the link below on the The Five Sins Against Our Lady:

[The Five Sins Against Our Lady](http://www.traditioninaction.org/religious/a019rpFiveSins_GuidoDelRose.htm)

> "My daughter, the motive is simple: there are five ways in which people offend and blaspheme against the Immaculate Heart of Mary:
>
> 1.the blasphemies against the Immaculate Conception,
>
> 2.against her virginity,
>
> 3.against the Divine Maternity, refusing at the same time to accept her as the Mother of all mankind,
>
> 4.those who try publicly to implant in the children's hearts indifference, contempt, and even hatred against this Immaculate Mother, and
>
> 5.those who insult her directly in her sacred images.

Looking on the Five Blasphemies against Blessed Virgin Mary is a direct attack on the Holy Spirit, basing it from St. Kolbe reflections & teachings and biblically from the word OVERSHADOWED.(Luke1:35).And the Overshadowing is paralleled to the Ark of the Covenant.

Jesus affirmed this kind of direct attack when he said "Saul, Saul why are you persecuting me?"(Acts9:4)

In conclusion, Matthew 12:32 is Jesus way of protecting His Mother from all evil attacking Her Dignity and God given role as the Mother of God (Theotokos) and recently Pope Francis declared Mary as the Mother of the Church.

So those who publicly attributes the approved Marian apparitions to the devil/Satan and the five specific action directed towards blaspheming the Dignity of the Blessed Virgin Mary are the UNFORGIVABLE SIN.

Comment: Although these sins offend Our lady's Immaculate Heart and the Holy Spirit, one can not declare them unforgiveable through private revelation, regardless of how serious they are. The Apparitions of Fatima are worthy of belief, but Catholics remain free to believe them or not. That is the nature of private revelation. They are not Divine or Public Revelation! That ended with the death of the last Apostle!

Comment: Ken Graham ..Fatima Messages are officially declared by Church as authentic divine revelation. To deny that Fatima Messages are not inspired or work of the Holy Spirit is going against the Church authority And Matthew 12:32 is very specific anyone who attributes the work of the HS to the devil is the Unforgivable Sin. And the 5 Blasphemy against BVM being animated by the HS in Her thoughts, words & actions  is a perfect description of the said verse. Jesus clearly protecting the dignity of His Mother.

Comment: Ken Graham it is noteworthy to notice the description of sins against BVM as blasphemies and not slander... Something to ponder. Godbless